# How to update classification layers without changing weights for convolutional layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a CNN with numerous convolutional layers. To each of these convolutional layers I have attached a classifier, to check outputs of intermediary layers. After losses have been produced for each of these classifiers, I want to update the weights for the classifier without touching the weights for the convolutional layers. This code:

```
for i in range(len(loss_per_layer)):
    loss_per_layer[i].backward(retain_graph=True)
    self.classifiers[i].weight.data -= self.learning_rate * self.alpha[i] * self.classifiers[i].weight.grad.data
    self.classifiers[i].bias.data -= self.learning_rate * self.alpha[i] * self.classifiers[i].bias.grad.data
```

allows me to do so if the classifier consists of a singular nn.Linear layer. However, my classifiers are of the shape:

```
self.classifiers.append(nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(int(feature_map * input_shape[1] * input_shape[2]), 100),
    nn.ReLU(True),
    nn.Dropout(),
    nn.Linear(100, self.num_classes),
    nn.Sigmoid(),
    ))
```

How can I update the weights of the Sequential block without touching the rest of the network? I have recently changed from keras to pytorch and so am unsure on how exactly to utilize the optimizer.step() function for this situation, but I have a suspicion it can be done using that.

Please note, I need a generic solution for a Sequential block of any shape, as it will change in future iterations of the model.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your model as below:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, conv_layers, classifier):
           super().__init__()
           self.conv_layers = conv_layers
           self.classifier = classifier

       def forward(self,x):
           x = self.conv_layers(x)
           return self.classifier(x)
```

When declaring optimizer, only pass the parameters that you want to be updated.

```
       model = Model(conv_layers, classifier)            
       optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

Now when you will do

```
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       model.zero_grad()
```

only classifier params will be updated.

EDIT: After OP's comment, I am adding below for more generic use cases.

A more generic scenario

```
   class Model(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, modules):
           super().__init__()
           # supposing you have multiple modules declared like below. 
           # You can also keep them as an array or dict too. 
           # For this see nn.ModuleList or nn.ModuleDict in pytorch 
           self.module0 = modules[0]
           self.module1 = modules[1]
           #..... and so on

       def forward(self,x):
           # implement forward 

   # model and optimizer declarations
   model = Model(modules)  
   # assuming we want to update module0 and module1          
   optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
       model.module0.parameters(), 
       model.module1.parameters()
   ], lr=lr)
   # you can also provide different learning rate for different modules. 
   # See [documentation][https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html]
   
   # when training  
   loss.backward()
   optimizer.step()
   model.zero_grad()
   # use model.zero_grad to remove gradient computed for all the modules.
   # optimizer.zero_grad only removes gradient for parameters that were passed to it.
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this still work if: I have two conv layers, I attach the second conv layer to the first. Then I attach classifier to the first conv layer, and a classifier to the second conv layer. I then want to update each classifier with the gradient of the loss coming from that classifier. I think I'd need to make a separate optimizer for each classifier then, right?

Comment: I see what you mean, I am updating the answer to reflect a more generic scenario. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to do the trick algorithmically. However, I am now getting an error stating: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation. I feel like I've set "inplace=False" everywhere its possible. Could it have something to do with the multiple output layers being updated?

Comment: @Kroshtan That should not be due to this... most likely. I can see where that might be creating the problem if you could share the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a builtin - or custom - [`torch.optim.Optimizer`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/optimizer.py), then you don't need to perform the parameter update by hand. You can simply freeze the layer(s) you don't want to update (by deactivating their `requires_grad` flag). Calling `.backward()` on your loss, then `optimizer.step()` will only update the classifier.

Depending on your `torch.nn.Module` model architecture, you can something like this:

```
for param in model.feature_extractor.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Where `model.feature_extractor` would be the head of your model containing the convolutional layers (*i.e.* the feature extractor). You can loop on any module this way, and `.parameters()` will loop over all parameters of this module children's parameters to deactivate `requires_grad`.